# Handling null values when parsing JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, event-handling

I want to import data using JSON, but some of the data is null, as shown:

```
[
    {
        "atasan": "name ",
        "kode_agen": "number",
        "jenis": "Regional",
        "no_aaji": "number* ",
        "nama_agen": "name"
    },
    {
        "atasan": "name ",
        "kode_agen": "number"
    },
    {
        "atasan": "name ",
        "kode_agen": "number",
        "jenis": "Agency",
        "nama_agen": "name"
    }
]
```

My question is what is the proper way to handle this null data? This is my source code:

```
try {
    JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray jsonArray = j.takeJson(url);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("atasan", c.get("atasan").toString());
        map.put("kode_agen", c.get("kode_agen").toString());
        map.put("jenis", c.get("jenis").toString());
        map.put("no_aaji", c.get("no_aaji").toString());
        map.put("nama_agen", c.get("nama_agen").toString());
        AgenList.add(map);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope somebody can help me to solve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
JSONObject c  = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

if (c.has("atasan")) 
    map.put("atasan", c.get("atasan").toString());
if (c.has("nama_agen")) 
    map.put("nama_agen", c.get("nama_agen").toString());
```

Comment: In order to keep the JSON structure consistent, I'd recommend to put JSONObject.Null rather than skipping fields from the object.

Comment: And just to explain a little bit why this must work, consider:

`map.put("kode_agen", c.get("kode_agen").toString());`

If `c.get("kode_agen")` returns null, you'll wind up with a NullPointerException.  Always check before using, hence `has().`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're expecting to have happen if there is a null value.  But it's also important to understand what is going on.  When you're calling c.get("atasan") and it is returning null, you can't continue with the .toString() call.  It's the same as saying null.toString()...just can't do that.

So just check for null then decide what to do.

If you want to put null or "" into the map if the field/attribute in the json object is null you can do something like what Naveen has or:

```
map.put("atasan", c.has("atasan") ? c.get("atasan").toString() : "");
```

or (if you want null instead)

```
map.put("atasan", c.has("atasan") ? c.get("atasan").toString() : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the parameters which may exist or not but this should not terminate the code. So for that, we need to use if and else statement.
In if statement you can use has() to check whether the parameter exists or not.
In case if has() doesn't work then you can try null check using isNULL() or like
`if(c!=null&&c.get("kode_agen")!=null)  map.put("kode_agen",c.get("kode_agen").toString());` 
 
 to check whether the value is null or not.

There can be a case when the JSON has stored value like this code
 `"kode_agen":null` 
then you need to ignore this kind of value because this may throw an error as null value
for this you can write,
 `if (!c.get("kode_agen").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")`
So you can say that, the conditions in if and else completely depends on JSON

```
JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       if(c.has("atasan"))
        map.put("atasan", c.get("atasan").toString());
       else
        map.put("atasan","null");
       if(c.has("kode_agen"))
        map.put("kode_agen", c.get("kode_agen").toString());
       else
        map.put("kode_agen","null");
       if(c.has("jenis"))
        map.put("jenis", c.get("jenis").toString());
       else
        map.put("jenis","null");
       if(c.has("no_aaji"))
        map.put("no_aaji", c.get("no_aaji").toString());
       else
        map.put("no_aaji","null");
       if(c.has("nama_agen"))
        map.put("nama_agen", c.get("nama_agen").toString());
       else
        map.put("nama_agen","null");        
        AgenList.add(map);
```